# help simplify if while list loop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
....
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

could understand the code on the above well.

1, could i delete the if and while condition? using `<?php the_post();?>` directly.

2, i feel the `if (have_posts())` is the same as the `while (have_posts())` .is it  redundance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**#1**: Calling `the_post` without a loop will only let you display a single post. This could be desirable on single-post pages, for example, where the `while` loop is often omitted:

```
<?php
// single.php
if ( have_posts() ):
    the_post();
?>
<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<? else: ?>
<p>No post found.</p>
<? endif ?>
```

---

**#2**: You're correct — the snippet you posted is redundant in its combination of `if` and `while`.

In most themes, however, this is the usage:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ):
    while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
?>
<div class="post"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>No posts found.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The use of the `if` statement in this case allows you to display something if there are no posts at all. If we were to just use the `while` loop in that code, pages without any posts would output nothing.

Comment: oh,damn it. i found this code <?php
if ( have_posts() ):
    while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
?>using in the default theme single.php? it's a  redundant!because in the single.php,it's only one post, it's useless to use the while loop.am i right?

Comment: Yes, it is redundant, but it's not too much to worry about. [WordPress's default theme uses it as well](http://phpxref.com/xref/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyten/single.php.source.html#l15).

Answer (score 1):

`while(have_postS())` will automatically evaluate `have_postS()` as by `if(have_postS())`

but it will continue as long as it is `true` (since it is a loop), if you have to loop and some  mechanism that terminates loop, then use `while`

else

for once `if` will do better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Wordpress, but by the looks of it, has_posts() returns either a truthy or falsy value. The `while` loop only executes if a truthy value is passed as the condition, so yes, you can reduce it to a whoopin 3 lines:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
....
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Edit: Put this as yet another example as to why copy-pasting code is bad...

Comment: why your code using  endif;? there is no if condition in your code? thanks for your answer.