# Can someone explain this piece of PHP code?

Tags: php

```
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

If `have-posts()` is true, then ... I don't understand the placement of the `:`.

Comment: Do you have a PHP programming book? I'll bet it explains the placement of the `:` in the chapter on control flow statements.

Comment: I lost count as to how many duplicates I found related to this type of *alternate* syntax. Here's one of many http://stackoverflow.com/q/5752515/ Googling your code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I agree there probably are dupes to this, unfortunately the OP didn't know the term "*alternate syntax*" to have searched with. Although, the one you linked to is not a dupe. Different question scope and no answer covers this question.

Comment: @James The link I gave above contains `if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` which is 95% of what's in the link above. I would call that a duplicate.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The entire scope of this question is "*I don't understand the placement of the :*", which is not asked nor answered in the question you proposed as a dupe. The alleged dupe is talking about not having the WP loop, and nothing relating to "alternate syntax". Surely a dupe is not defined simply by a question having the same *words* in them?

Comment: @James As I said, that was one of the questions I found. The others I should have included in a comment, where alternate syntax is mentioned in there. Yet, I would have been shot down because of it, had I closed the question based on that; the alternate syntax questions I found but did not include in my comment. I didn't come up with the system, Stack did and `they encourage us to do so`; whether syntax knowledge is known or unknown.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to write compound statements, like `if` and `while` bodies, in PHP. You can surround the body with `{ ... }`:

```
while (condition) {
    body
}
```

or you can use `:` and an `endXXX` statement:

```
while (condition) :
    body
endwhile;
```

Your code uses the second form. It's a pretty common style when mixed with `<?php ... ?>` within the body, so that the end of the block stands out more than:

```
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your answer is more complete =) +1

Answer (score 1):

The functions are how Wordpress allows you to manipulate the posts stored in the database.

The `:` is just an alternative syntax, with the `:` replacing curly braces in the `while`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action

> 1. First, it checks whether any posts were discovered with the
>      have_posts() function.
> 2. If there were any posts, a PHP while loop is started. A while loop
>      will continue to execute as long as the condition in the parenthesis
>      is logically true. So, as long as the function have_posts() returns
>      a true value, the while loop will keep looping (repeating).

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures;
>   namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic
>   form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon
>   (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;,
>   or endswitch;, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This is using the braceless alternate syntax of `while`: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Therefore, the code above is doing the same as this:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
   while ( have_posts() ){
     the_post();
     the_content();
   }
}
```